# loop iteration - rewriting the output file

Tags: python, loops, io

I currently have this code that successfully reads information from two sources and correctly formats them into an output file \_spec_final.t15. Currently the information prints one after another, but I would like it to print the information for one line/file then overwrite it with the next iteration. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
with open('\\_spec_final.t15', 'w') as f:
    with open('info.txt', 'rt') as infofile:
        for count, line in enumerate(infofile): 
            print count
            lat = float(line[88:94]) 
            lon = float(line[119:127])
            year = int(line[190:194])
            month = int(line[195:197])
            day = int(line[198:200])
            hour = int(line[201:203])
            minute = int(line[204:206])
            second = int(line[207:209])
            dur = float(line[302:315])
            numpoints = float(line[655:660])
            fov = line[481:497] # field of view?
            sza = float(line[418:426])
            snr = 0.0000 
            roe = 6396.2 
            res = 0.5000
            lowwav = float(lowwav)
            highwav = float(highwav)
            spacebw = (highwav - lowwav)/ numpoints

            d = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
            f.write('{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>8.1f}'.format(sza,roe,lat,lon,snr)) # line 1
            f.write("\n")
            f.write('{:>10d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}'.format(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)) # line 2
            f.write("\n")
            f.write( ('{:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)) + "UT Solar Azimuth:" + ('{:>6.3f}'.format(sza)) + " Resolution:" + ('{:>6.4f}'.format(res)) + " Duration:" + ('{:>6.2f}'.format(dur))) # line 3
            f.write("\n")
            f.write('{:>21.13f}{:>26.13f}{:>24.17e}{:>12f}'.format(lowwav,highwav,spacebw,numpoints)) # line 4
            f.write("\n")

            with open(files[count], 'r') as g:
                for line in g:
                    wave_no, intensity = [float(item) for item in line.split()]
                    if lowwav <= wave_no <= highwav:
                        f.write(str(intensity) + '\n')
```

Comment: just move the line where you open the fiile for writing inside of the loop. that way every time you open it, it will truncate the file first.

Comment: move it where? do you mean unindent it?

Comment: move it inside the loop: as in, the `for` loop header comes first, and in that loop you have your `open(..., 'w')` line

Comment: if I do that it messes up the count, which is crucial to getting the other files in the second with open loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open and write to the file after you read in `infofile`.

It will open and overwrite `\_spec_final.t15` with each iteration.

```
with open('info.txt', 'rt') as infofile:   
    for count, line in enumerate(infofile):
        print count
        with open('\\_spec_final.t15', 'w') as f:
```

Comment: the count isn't accurate if I do this

Comment: Oops, I see the issue. How are you getting the next iteration? Each iteration of the for loop, you mean?

Comment: sorry I am confused by your question. the loop iterates by a for loop - for each line in info file it extracts info from that line in info file and the corresponding file in files(g). it does the iteration correctly i just want it to write over the file each time rather than add the info to the file

Comment: I edited my answer. I can't really tell what you're doing with \_spec_final.t15 so I can't say this will definitely solve your problems, but this should not mess up your count while overwriting the file with each iteration.